# How to show very long text in Textview

Tags: android, text, android-listview, textview

I have listview that content textview.
I try to show very long text(10.000 characters) in that textview.

When, the program was running.
There is no text in textview.

But, when i set text only 2000 characters, textview show the text.

How to show 10.000 characters in one textview?

Here's my XML:

```
   <TextView
            android:id="@+id/message"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:autoLink="all"
            android:maxEms="1000"
            android:maxLength="10000"
            android:maxLines="1000"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:text="Message"
            android:textColor="@color/Black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/txt_message" />
```

Comment: is the text is *static* or *dynamic*

Comment: The text is dynamic.

Comment: Why are you setting maxLength and maxLines?

Comment: You probably need to scroll to see the rest?

Comment: are these `String` coming from `webservice`?